Gradle layout.buildDirectory Read-only file system issue
So I'm following Gradle's recommendation to remove the deprecated $project.buildDir property for the lint settings.
It was: htmlOutput file("$project.buildDir/outputs/lint/lint.html") 
It became: htmlOutput layout.buildDirectory.file("/outputs/lint/lint.html").get().asFile
Now when running lint I receive the next error:
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /outputs: Read-only file system.
I'm wondering if I'm missing something, or if something should be done additionally.

from the same recommendation link:
htmlOutput = layout.buildDirectory.file("outputs/lint/lint.html").get().asFile

tried it in 8.4 and it worked fine. Try removing the leading slash from the file path...

Yay, that's worked, missed such an obvious thing. Thank you!

Please someone put it as an answer, so I'll accept it. Btw, any reason behind such a behavior?

The leading slash turns the path into an absolute one.

As per the same recommendation link, it should be: htmlOutput = layout.buildDirectory.file("outputs/lint/lint.html").get().asFile
Moved to the answers from comments.
